# Create a table of two types in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-types

I have created two types:

```
Create  Type info_typ_1 AS (
Prod_id integer, 
category integer);

Create Type movie_typ AS(
title varchar(50),
actor varchar(50),
price float);
```

And I want to create a table that consists of these two types. I know that for a table that consists of one type, it's:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 of type1
(
  primary key(prod_id)
);
```

Is there any way to do that for the two types I created above?

What I tried doing(which is wrong), is creating a third type that contains the first two:

```
Create Type info_ AS (
info info_typ_1,
movie movie_typ);
```

and then creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 of info_
(
  primary key(Prod_id)
);
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "prod_id" named in key does not exist
LINE 3:   primary key(Prod_id)
          ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "prod_id" named in key does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 43
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make `prod_id` the primary key of `table1` because the only columns are the two composite types `info` and `movie`. You cannot access the base types of these composite types in a `PRIMARY KEY` clause.

What you were trying to do works with a pk constraint on `info` or `movie`.
Except, it's probably not what you were looking for, which is not possible this way.

You could implement something *like* this with ...

#### [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html)

Here you can inherit from multiple parent tables (substitute for your types). Example:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  prod_id integer
 ,category integer
);

CREATE TABLE movie (
   title text
  ,actor text
  ,price float
);

CREATE  TABLE movie_info (
   PRIMARY KEY(prod_id)             -- now we can use the base column!
)
INHERITS (info, movie);

INSERT INTO movie_info (prod_id, category, title, actor, price)
VALUES (1, 2, 'who donnit?', 'James Dean', '15.90');

SELECT * FROM movie_info;
```

[-> **SQLfiddle** demonstrating both.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ba33b/1)

Be sure to read about [limitations of inheritance in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS).

Comment: is there any way to do this with `type` ? Instead of creating three tables

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: Inheritance requires tables. I don't see any harm in creating tables, though. You could even store those away in some dedicated schema. [Like demonstrated in this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgresql-database/20576324#20576324)