# Is there a more succinct way to cast query results to a type?

Tags: postgresql, types, casting

I'm often casting query results to user defined types.   Consider this simplistic example:

```
test=# create type test_type as  (a int, b int);
CREATE TYPE
test=# create table test_table (a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into test_table values (1,2);
INSERT 0 1
test=# select r::test_type from (select * from test_table t) as r;
   r   
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

For a lot of my queries having a subquery is necessary and that works great. However, sometimes it's a simple 1 to 1 mapping from table to type, like in the example above.

Is there an easier way to express this?

When I try what seems obvious to me I get errors:

```
test=# select t::test_type from test_table t;
ERROR:  cannot cast type test_table to test_type
LINE 1: select t::test_type from test_table t;
                ^
```

Comment: Consider the update to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ROW` construct with wildcard column expansion for this.

```
regress=> select ROW(t.*)::testtype from testtable t;
  row  
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

Comment: I tried `(t.*)::test_type` assuming `(t.*)` would return a `row` but failed to notice it does not. And as it did not work I didn't bother to try the explicit `row` construct. How come `(t.*)` does not return a row? I guess it is some compilation issue.

Comment: I also tried (t.*)::test_type during my 'guesses' thinking the same thing.  I assumed (t.*) would return a row too.

Comment: I did some more research Craig, from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html 4.2.13 "The key word ROW is optional when there is more than one expression in the list"

Comment: @bhirt Yeah ... I think that at parse time `t.*` is still a single expression. It still seems odd; I'll investigate if time permits and see exactly what the parser and rewriter are doing here.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto wildcard expansion in Pg is a bit hacky. It's essentially macro expansion partway through the parse phase, which causes some interesting oddities. Nonetheless, I expected `(t.*)::sometype` to work myself and was surprised it didn't.

Comment: May be related to this oddity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271. On a closer look: I get `ERROR:  cannot cast type testtable to testtype` for an attempt on `(t.*)::test_type`. So this seems to be an unrelated issue with the missing cast.

Answer (score 3):

A bit easier

```
select t::test_type
from (table test_table) t;
```

or create your own cast

```
create function test_table_2_test_type (test_table_value test_table)
returns test_type as $$
    select test_table_value.a, test_table_value.b;
$$ language sql;

create cast (test_table as test_type)
with function test_table_2_test_type (test_table);

select t::test_type 
from test_table t;
   t   
-------
 (1,2)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html

Comment: For anyone like me wondering about that `TABLE test_table` example, it's just [shorthand for `SELECT * FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE). I also didn't know you could just list the table name in the SELECT list as though it was a column like that, but then I've never had a situation where I needed to...

Answer (score 2):

#### Casting techniques

Or you can cast to `text` as intermediary type, since *everything* can be cast to and from `text`:

```
SELECT t::text::test_type FROM test_table t;
```

This is the "catch-all" ad-hoc solution for all kinds of similar problems, where you know types to be compatible, but a direct cast is missing.

The `ROW` constructor as [demonstrated by @Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923892/939860) is more elegant for this case.
Creating a new cast like [demonstrated by @Clodoaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918547/939860) is smarter for cases you are going to use regularly.

However, the superior solution would be to ***remove the problem***.

#### Simple solution: use only the table type

For the simple case demonstrated, just don't create an additional type at all. Use the type `test_table` that's created implicitly automatically. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

> `CREATE TABLE` also automatically creates a data type that represents
>   the composite type corresponding to one row of the table.

So, just:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (a int, b int);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1,2);

SELECT r FROM test_table r;
   r   
-------
 (1,2)
```

But the demo in your question is probably just a simplification. For a general solution:

### Multiple tables sharing the same type

Postgres is called an **ORDBMS** (object-relational database management system) by some, for a reason. Use ***typed tables***.

Create the common type explicitly or reuse the implicit type of the "master" table.
This is ..
.. *not* [**inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565183/create-a-table-of-two-types-in-postgresql/21565888#21565888).
.. different from `CREATE TABLE t (LIKE master)`
.. different from `CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM master LIMIT 0`

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#AEN72690)

> `OF` ***type_name***
>
> Creates a typed table, which takes its structure from the specified composite type (name optionally schema-qualified). A typed
>   table is tied to its type; for example the table will be dropped if
>   the type is dropped (with `DROP TYPE ... CASCADE`).
>
> When a typed table is created, then the data types of the columns are determined by the underlying composite type and are not specified
>   by the `CREATE TABLE` command. But the `CREATE TABLE` command can add
>   defaults and constraints to the table and can specify storage parameters.

#### Recipe

```
CREATE TYPE master AS (a int, b int);
```

*Or*

```
CREATE TABLE master (a int, b int);
```

Then use that type to create more tables of the same type:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 OF master;
CREATE TABLE table2 OF master;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1,2);
```

```
SELECT r FROM table1 r;          -- returns composite type "table1"
SELECT r::master FROM table1 r; -- returns composite type "master"
```

The composite types `master`, `table1`, `table2` are 100% identical and can be cast into each other automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I'd gone to the trouble of creating a new type, I think I'd use it in the `create table` statement.

```
create table test_table (t test_type);
insert into test_table values ((2, 3));
-- No cast needed here.
select * from test_table;
```

```
t
test_type
--
(2, 3)
```

```
-- No cast needed here.
select t from (select * from test_table) x;
```

```
t
test_type
--
(2, 3)
```

If you have to manufacture a value of type "test_type" on the fly, use a row constructor and a type cast. I think the "::" syntax is more concise than CAST(), but both work.

```
select (2, 3)::test_type
```

```
row
test_type
--
(2, 3)
```

Comment: If I'm reading the other examples right, this isn't quite equivalent: you've create a table with a single multi-valued column, but the other queries are taking a row from a multi-columned table.

Comment: I think the last part of my answer, "If you have to manufacture a value of type 'test_type'" is similar to what everyone else is talking about. (I used literals; columns work the same way.) But my main point is that using the user-defined type in the table definition can avoid the need for a type cast altogether.

Comment: Fair enough; it does come with the major downside that you then *have* to refer to that composite row type, because `SELECT a FROM test_table` no longer works. Nor can you easily create indexes, constraints, etc referencing the individual fields.

Comment: *Easily* is in the eye of the beholder. If there's a good reason to *have* a composite type--like the intrinsic `date`, `timestamp`, `point`, etc.--then `select (t).a from test_table` isn't a very high price to pay for it. PostgreSQL support indexes on expressions, including the fields of composite types.

Comment: @IMSoP: You might both be interested in `typed tables` for the best of both worlds. I added details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The question I posted was just a simplistic example to demonstrate the issues I was running up against.   What's actually being done is a lot more complex and these types really don't map to tables in their normalized form.  In fact my actual problem was with views, but it was easier to demonstrate the issues with tables.