# Left join with dynamic table name derived from column

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, dynamic-sql, tablename

I am new in PostgreSQL and I wonder if it's possible to use `number` from table `tbc` as part of the table name in left join `'pa' || number`. So for example if number is 456887 I want left join with table pa456887. Something like this:

```
SELECT tdc.cpa, substring(tdc.ku,'[0-9]+') AS number, paTab.vym 
FROM public."table_data_C" AS tdc
LEFT JOIN concat('pa' || number) AS paTab ON (paTab.cpa = tdc.cpa)
```

And I want to use only PostgreSQL, not additional code in PHP for example.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible data model. You should fix that instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, but what is the fix when you have a requirement like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either way, you need dynamic SQL.

### Table name as given parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_number int)
  RETURNS TABLE (cpa int, nr text, vym text) AS  -- adapt to actual data types!
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT t.cpa, substring(t.ku,'[0-9]+'), p.vym 
       FROM   public."table_data_C" t
       LEFT   JOIN %s p USING (cpa)'
     , 'pa' || _number
     );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo(456887)
```

Generally, you would sanitize table names with `format ( %I )` to avoid SQL injection. With just an `integer` as dynamic input that's not necessary. More details and links in this related answer:
[INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

#### Data model

There may be good reasons for the data model. Like partitioning / sharding or separate privileges ...
If you don't have such a good reason, consider consolidating multiple tables with identical schema into one and add the `number` as column. Then you don't need dynamic SQL.

Consider [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html). Then you can add a condition on `tableoid` to only retrieve rows from a given child table:

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table
WHERE  tableoid = 'pa456887'::regclass
```

[Be aware of limitations for inheritance, though.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) Related answers:

- [Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from/24581769#24581769)
- [Select (retrieve) all records from multiple schemas using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgresql-database/20576324#20576324)

### Name of 2nd table depending on value in 1st table

Deriving the name of the join table from values in the first table dynamically complicates things.

#### For only a few tables

`LEFT JOIN` each on `tableoid`. There is only one match per row, so use `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT t.*, t.tbl, COALESCE(p1.vym, p2.vym, p3.vym) AS vym
FROM  (
   SELECT cpa, ('pa' || substring(ku,'[0-9]+'))::regclass AS tbl
   FROM   public."table_data_C"
   -- WHERE <some condition>
   ) t
LEFT   JOIN pa456887 p1 ON p1.cpa = t.cpa AND p1.tableoid = t.tbl
LEFT   JOIN pa456888 p2 ON p2.cpa = t.cpa AND p2.tableoid = t.tbl
LEFT   JOIN pa456889 p3 ON p3.cpa = t.cpa AND p3.tableoid = t.tbl
```

#### For many tables

Combine a loop with dynamic queries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_number int)
  RETURNS TABLE (cpa int, nr text, vym text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _nr text;
BEGIN
FOR _nr IN
   SELECT DISTINCT substring(ku,'[0-9]+')
   FROM   public."table_data_C"
LOOP
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT t.cpa, _nr, p.vym 
       FROM   public."table_data_C" t
       LEFT   JOIN %I p USING (cpa)
       WHERE  t.ku LIKE (_nr || '%')'
     , 'pa' || _nr
     );
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But this number 456887 which I entry to foo() function is number from database (It is this number from first select substring(t.ku,'[0-9]+')).

Comment: @LubosK.: That makes it more difficult then. I really think your data model should be improved. For now: How many rows do you retrieve at once? And how many different tables do you join to? Can there be multiple distinct values in `tdc.ku` starting with the same number?

Comment: @LubosK.: I added two solutions that should cover all cases.