# Query from many similar tables postgresql - Dinamically change the table on from clause

Tags: postgresql

Im new in DB world but I'm so excited about it.

So I have extract some data from a DB where I have a table called movements and others called movements_YYYYMM where the detailed information is so YYYY is the year and MM the month, So I have,

So I have  tables like movements_202001 or movements_200701, th  thing is that I need to extract some information from movements, and depending of column lapse on it I need to extract some information from "movements_+.movements.lapse" but I don't know how to properly concatenate this info in postgres.

And I don't even know if this type of querys are possible.

I was thinking in somethig like:

```
SELECT mv.prfix||' '||mv.number AS invoice, mvm.count
FROM movements mv, movements_+mvm.lapse mvm...
```

I know that's not the right way to concatenate

Thanks in advance for  your help.

Comment: Hi, interestng, not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775635/left-join-with-dynamic-table-name-derived-from-column - could also create a view from multiple tables so you just join against the view

Comment: If you want to query all of this information at once, and all of these tables have the same structure, perhaps consider storing them all in the same table?

Comment: It is not possible, they have a similar structure but not equal, some columns are equal, and for this matter I just use that columns.