# PL/pgSQL Looping through multiple schema, tables and rows

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a database with multiple identical schemas. There is a number of tables all named 'tran_...' in each schema.  I want to loop through all 'tran_' tables in all schemas and pull out records that fall within a specific date range. This is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."configChanges"(starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF character varying AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    tbl_row RECORD;
    tbl_name VARCHAR(50);
    tran_row RECORD;
    out_record VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
    FOR tbl_row IN
       SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname LIKE 'ivr%' AND tablename LIKE 'tran_%'
    LOOP
        tbl_name := tbl_row.schemaname || '.' || tbl_row.tablename;
         FOR tran_row IN
            SELECT * FROM tbl_name
            WHERE ch_edit_date >= starttime AND ch_edit_date <= endtime
         LOOP
            out_record := tbl_name || '    ' || tran_row.ch_field_name;
                        RETURN NEXT out_record;
         END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I attempt to run this, I get:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "tbl_name" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE ch_edit_date >= starttime AND c...
> ```

Comment: Please *always* mention your version of Postgres. May be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826678/939860) already provided a fix for your basic error.

However, since your `tbl_name` is actually schema-qualified (two *separate* identifiers in : `schema.table`), it cannot be escaped as a whole with `%I` in [**`format()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html). You have to escape each identifier individually.

Aside from that, I suggest a different approach. The outer loop is necessary, but the inner loop can be replaced with a simpler and more efficient **set-based approach**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.config_changes(_start timestamp, _end timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename)
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  schemaname LIKE 'ivr%'
      AND    tablename LIKE 'tran_%'
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format (
         $$
         SELECT %1$L || '    ' || ch_field_name
         FROM   %1$s
         WHERE  ch_edit_date BETWEEN $1 AND $2
         $$, _tbl
         )
      USING _start, _end;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- You have to use dynamic SQL to parametrize identifiers (or code), like @Pavel already told you. With [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN60493) you can return the result of a dynamic query directly. Examples:

  - [Return SETOF rows from PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864911/return-setof-rows-from-postgresql-function/17865708#17865708)
  - [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
- Remember that identifiers have to be treated as unsafe user input in dynamic SQL and must always be sanitized to avoid syntax errors and **SQL injection**:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- Note how I escape table and schema separately:

  ```
   quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename)
  ```
- Consequently I just use `%s` to insert the already escaped table name in the later query. And `%L` to escape it a string literal for output.
- I like to prepend parameter and variable names with `_` to avoid naming conflicts with column names. No other special meaning.

There is a slight difference compared to your original function. This one returns an escaped identifier (double-quoted only where necessary) as table name, e.g.:

```
"WeIRD name"
```

instead of

```
WeIRD name
```

#### Much simpler yet

*If possible*, use [**inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html) to obviate the need for above function altogether. Complete example:

- [Select (retrieve) all records from multiple schemas using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas/20576324#20576324)

Comment: I tried the above and got the following
    `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ivr27258"`
    `LINE 2:                         SELECT ivr27258.tran_control_record ...`
    `QUERY:`
        `SELECT ivr27258.tran_control_record || '    ' || ch_field_name FROM ivr27258.tran_control_record WHERE ch_edit_date BETWEEN starttime AND endtime`

Comment: @Deric: Sorry, the string literal wasn't properly escaped. Should be fixed now.

Comment: This got me 99% of the way there.  The only change I had to make was altering the QUERY to `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
                        $$
                        SELECT %1$L || '    ' || ch_field_name FROM %1$s WHERE ch_edit_date BETWEEN '%2$s' AND '%3$s'
                        $$, tbl_name, starttime, endtime`

Comment: @Deric: Ah, right. I forgot the function parameters. Pass *values* with a `USING` clause, that's much better than concatenating them. See update above

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a plpgsql variable as SQL table name or SQL column name. In this case you have to use dynamic SQL:

```
FOR tran_row IN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I
                   WHERE ch_edit_date >= starttime AND ch_edit_date <= endtime', tbl_name)
LOOP
   out_record := tbl_name || '    ' || tran_row.ch_field_name;
   RETURN NEXT out_record;
END LOOP;
```