# Show child table name when selecting a row from parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I have a table with inheritance with 4 child tables.
How can I know the source table of a specific row?

Answer (score 2):

From [PostgreSQL documentation on inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html):

> By doing a join with `pg_class` you can see the actual table names:
>
> ```
> SELECT p.relname, c.name, c.altitude
> FROM cities c, pg_class p
> WHERE c.altitude > 500 AND c.tableoid = p.oid;
> ```

In the example above, `p.relname` would return the specific child table the row was fetched from.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system column [**`tableoid`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html), it's available for *any* table.
But you don't need to join to `pg_class`. Just cast to `regclass` (and then to `text`, optionally).

```
SELECT tbl_id, tableoid::regclass::text AS source
FROM   tbl
WHERE  <some condition>;
```

Related:

- [Select (retrieve) all records from multiple schemas using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas/20576324#20576324)