# Function to loop through and select data from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, set-returning-functions

I'm new to Postgres and have a database with multiple tables of the same structure. I need to select data from each table that matches certain criteria.

I could do this with a bunch of `UNION` queries, but the number of tables I need to search can change over time, so I don't want to hard code it like that. I've been trying to develop a function that will loop through specific tables (they have a common naming convention) and return a table of records, but I'm not getting any results when I query the function. Function code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.internalid_formaltable_name_lookup()
  RETURNS TABLE(natural_id text, name text, natural_id_numeric text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    formal_table text;
begin
  FOR formal_table IN
    select table_name from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema = 'public' and table_name like 'formaltable%'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'SELECT natural_id, name, natural_id_numeric
             FROM ' || formal_table || 
           ' WHERE natural_id_numeric IN (
                select natural_id_numeric from internal_idlookup
                where internal_id = ''7166571'')';
    RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;
 Return;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am not getting any errors when I try to use the function, but it's not returning any rows:

```
SELECT * From internalid_formaltable_name_lookup();
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Can't you create a parent table and inherit children so you can query just one table if those have a similar structure?

Comment: Also your expression in "RETURN NEXT expr" is empty.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.internalid_formaltable_name_lookup()
  RETURNS TABLE(natural_id text, name text, natural_id_numeric text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   formal_table text;
BEGIN
   FOR formal_table IN
      SELECT quote_ident(table_name)
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
      AND    table_name LIKE 'formaltable%'
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      'SELECT t.natural_id, t.name, t.natural_id_numeric
       FROM   internal_idlookup i 
       JOIN   public.' || formal_table || ' t USING (natural_id_numeric)
       WHERE  i.internal_id = 7166571';   -- assuming internal_id is numeric
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

You have to use [**`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to return each *set of rows*.
`EXECUTE`, followed by `RETURN NEXT`, does not do what you seem to expect *at all*.

You need to sanitize identifiers. I am using `quote_ident()` here. Or your query will break with non-standard identifiers and allow SQL injection!

Converted your `col IN (sub-select)` to a more efficient `JOIN`.

This is subtly different from using `a bunch of UNION queries`. It does *not* remove duplicate rows, and actually works like [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION).

Personally, I'd rather build this on the system catalog `pg_class` or the system view `pg_tables`. Details:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Then you can work with the `pg_class.oid::regclass` to escape and schema-qualify table names automatically. Details:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Search across multiple tables and also display table name in resulting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475213/search-across-multiple-tables-and-also-display-table-name-in-resulting-rows/22475802#22475802)

But that depends on the details of your requirements and ... taste.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to use `quote_ident()`. I used `quote_literal()` since the former add double-quotes (") whereas the latter singe-quotes (').