# How to get columns name from an array for a select query in Postgres

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need query a table getting the columns name from an array...
something like this

```
$$
DECLARE
   column varchar[] := array['column1','column2','column3'];
   _row record;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. array_length(column, 1)
    LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE '%: %', i, column[i];
       select t.column[i] into _row from table t;
       RAISE NOTICE '%: %', i, _row.column[i];
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Did you get it? Is it possible?

Comment: Could you include an example of the input and desired output, and explain what happens with your current attempt?

Comment: The output would be the value in the table from the field in the array.. the above function should process something like..

select t.field1 into _row from table t;
select t.field2 into _row from table t;
select t.field3 into _row from table t;

those fields are extracted from the array

Comment: Ah, OK, so by "field" you mean "column", and what you're after is to dynamically create the SQL to reference different columns each time round the loop.

Comment: yeah!.. exactly!.. I'll correct.. I'm talking about the column.. 
How can I select those column from the array?

Comment: There is no function header? I don't expect a `DO` statement producing notices is the goal? You need to define what you want to return. A set of single values? A set of rows? Arrays? Of what data type exactly? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24892161/edit) your question. Do not squeeze essential information into comments.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to convert user input to `identifiers` or `code` in an SQL statement, you need **dynamic SQL**. Either concatenate the statement in your client an send it to the DB engine or (more efficiently) do it in PL/pgSQL (or some procedural server-side language) dynamically with `EXECUTE`. More details:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

#### Solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_columns(_cols text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (col text, val text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _col text;
BEGIN
   FOREACH _col IN ARRAY _cols LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      format('SELECT %1$L::text, %1$I::text FROM tbl t', _col);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_array_of_columns('{column1,column2}');
```

Returns (random values):

```
col     | val
--------+-----
column1 | 001
column1 | 002
column1 | 003
column2 | {foo,boo,foo}
column2 | {"",for,test}
column2 | {test,foo,boo}
```

#### Key elements:

- A matching `RETURNS` declaration.
- A way to ruturn your results, [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/postgresql-function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables/24621496#24621496) here.
- A [`FOREACH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop/9784986#9784986) loop in this particular case.
- [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to simplify string concatenation and escape names and values properly.
  Note the specifiers:
  `%1$L` ... first parameter as quoted literal.
  `%1$I` ... first parameter as properly escaped Identifier.

Note how I cast both columns to `text` (`::text`) to match the return type and make it work for *any* data type. Depending on exact requirements, this could be more specific.

Comment: hello, this answer helped me a lot with an unrelated problem, specifically `%1$L` and `%1$I` when trying to use `for loop` variable as a column name in a `select` query. could you point me to a good documentation where I could read further about, as you call them, *specifiers*? thanx

Comment: @Scaramouche: Some related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152529/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860. But I already linked to the documentation above. Follow the link to the manual for [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).