# How to get only the table names of a database in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, bash, postgresql, psql

I have a couple of bash scripts that query a mysql database and get the table names, I use the following command:

```
mysql -NBA --user=$DB_user --password=$DB_pass --database=$DB_name -e 'show tables'
```

With the -NBA parameters I filter the result and get something like this:

```
    categories
    colections
    colors
    files
```

In postgreSQL with psql I'm trying to achieve the same format, I'm reading the documentation and using the following parameters:

```
psql --username=$DB_user -W --host=$HOST --dbname=$DB_name -Atc '\dt'
```

An this is the best I can get

```
    public|categories|table|user
    public|colections|table|dbuser
    public|colors|table|dbuser
    public|files|table|dbuser
```

In the worst case I need to parse this to get only the names of the table, but if someone know the way to achieve what I want I be glad.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-tables.html

Comment: You can use awk to get just the table names in your bash script...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This SQL query gets the desired information (or any variants thereof):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema = 'public' -- mysql does not have schemas
ORDER  BY 1;
```

So from the shell:

```
psql --username=$DB_user -W --host=$HOST --dbname=$DB_name -Atc 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = \'public\' ORDER BY 1'
```

You may want to use `quote_ident(table_name)` to get escaped table names:

`;DELETE FROM users; --` becomes `";DELETE FROM users; --"`

- [Function to loop through and select data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/postgresql-function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables/24621496#24621496)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Note that you only get table names your current user has access to. About the information schema and system catalogs:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)