# Search where such a column can be found

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have database called test1 and many tables,how can I see the name of the tables in whichthere is a cell below the column 'jobs' with value bigger than 500?

Comment: You should show an understanding of the problem and describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is really two questions:

1. How do I find the tables that have a column named "jobs"?
2. How do I repeat a query against a list of tables?

For 1 - you can use the [columns view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) to find the tables that have a column named job.

For 2 - now that you know how to get your list of tables - you can build a query that runs against each table using the approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24621496/95076).