# Execute text string returned from function as a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function with the following "signature":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iterate_test()
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

...

That returns a query in text form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.date) AS date, AMD.adjusted_close AS AMD, GME.adjusted_close AS GME FROM clean_daily AS t1 INNER JOIN clean_daily AS AMD ON t1.date=AMD.date AND AMD.ticker='AMD' INNER JOIN clean_daily AS GME ON AMD.date=GME.date AND GME.ticker='GME' ORDER BY t1.date DESC;
```

How can I execute this string as a query? I have tried EXECUTE like this:

```
EXECUTE iterate_test();
EXECUTE QUERY iterate_test();
```

But I can't get it to work. How do I execute a data query in the form of text?

Full function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iterate_test()
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    DECLARE
        temprow record;
        str_query text := 'SELECT DISTINCT(t1.date) AS date';
        prev_table text := 't1';
    BEGIN
        FOR temprow IN SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE user_name='snigelnmjau'
        LOOP
            str_query := str_query || format(', %s.adjusted_close AS %s', temprow.ticker, temprow.ticker);
        END LOOP;

        str_query := str_query || format(' FROM clean_daily AS t1 ');

        FOR temprow IN SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE user_name='snigelnmjau'
        LOOP
            str_query := str_query || format(E'INNER JOIN clean_daily AS %s ON %s.date=%s.date AND %s.ticker=''%s'' ', temprow.ticker, prev_table, temprow.ticker, temprow.ticker, temprow.ticker);
            prev_table := temprow.ticker;
        END LOOP;
        str_query := str_query || 'ORDER BY t1.date DESC;';

        --EXECUTE str_query;
        RETURN str_query;
    END;
$$;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: use [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54103). See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
- [Function to loop through and select data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables/24621496#24621496)
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Your function with a couple of fixes, including one for the core question:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.iterate_test()
  RETURNS SETOF text  -- !!
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   temprow record;
   str_query text := 'SELECT DISTINCT t1.date';  -- !!
   prev_table text := 't1';
BEGIN
   FOR temprow IN
      SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE user_name = 'snigelnmjau'
   LOOP
      str_query := str_query || format(', %1$I.adjusted_close AS %1$I', temprow.ticker);  -- !!
   END LOOP;

   str_query := str_query || ' FROM clean_daily AS t1 ';  -- !!

   FOR temprow IN
      SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE user_name = 'snigelnmjau'
   LOOP
      str_query := str_query || format('JOIN clean_daily AS %1$I ON %2$I.date=%1$I.date AND %1$I.ticker=%1$L ', temprow.ticker, prev_table); -- !!
      prev_table := temprow.ticker;
   END LOOP;
   str_query := str_query || 'ORDER BY t1.date DESC';

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE str_query;  -- !!!!
END
$func$;
```

But the whole statement may possibly be generated in a single `SELECT` statement without looping (twice). And why `DISTINCT`?

Moreover, I am not convinced we need dynamic SQL to begin with. A plain query may be possible.