# How to perform same SQL query on many tables using FOR IN LOOP statement?

Tags: postgresql

I am just starting with functions and it seems like I went a bit over my head with this one)
So for example I need to execute `SELECT * FROM <table>` query. I need this query to be executed for all tables I have.
And list of table names is just another table,  so to get all table names I have to execute `SELECT table_names FROM meta_table_info`
How can I do this for many tables using some sort of cycle?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: So what to you want to do with the content of all those tables (=the result of all SELECTs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hello! I am not sure yet, but for starters maybe just combine results together  in a new table, or at least display those results just for debuging  purposes.

Comment: But they have different column count and column types...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Hello! For the sake of argument lets pretend that all of those tables are equal. I am just trying to get the concept of looping select query over several tables.

Comment: My recommendation is that you pick a different, more realistic problem to train your skills on. Weird requirements like that tend to have weird, complicated solutions that do not really help the learner.

Comment: maybe you can try using function  for loop to select the same table multiple times.

Comment: Found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables