# Database design - should two projects share the same table?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Background:
Two projects (A & B) under design at the same time both needs a new table(called `DocumentStore`) to store document/file under postgres.

But business logic around the document storage are different between project A & B, this means relationship around `DocumentStore` are different between A & B.

Let's make this a bit more concrete, see example below:

The Document storage table structure looks the same without constraints/ foreign Keys:

**Table `DocumentStore`**

```
DocUUID //unique Id for this document, PK, FK to other table depends on project 
fileName //file name
fileType //file type
FileContent //store file as blog
```

In project **A**, `DocumentStore.DocUUID` references `Email.EmailUUID`:

Note there is a one to many relationship between Email -> DocumentStore via the FK.

**Table `Email`**

```
EmailUUID //PK
subject
title
...
```

In project **B**, `DocumentStore.DocUUID` references `Letter.LetterUUID`:

Note there is a one to many relationship between Letter -> DocumentStore via the FK.

**Table `Letter`**

```
LetterUUID //PK
UserId
rightId
...
```

`Email` and `Letter` are completely different because of different of business logic.

---

My questions are:

1. Should I share this `DocumentStore` table between project A & B ?
2. If the answer to 1. is yes, then how? Through inheritance under postgres?
3. If the answer to 1. is no, should I create two table with the same structure but different table name and different foreign key ? One for project A and project B?

Comment: The core question is: are the same documents linked to email *and* letter often? How often?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: different document links to email & letter. It's gonna be more often for letter case(perhaps most cases), and less often for email case(maybe 2/10 cases). I am not sure why this is the core question ? Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If individual rows in documents are not shared between emails and letters, you'd better have separate tables to begin with. Your answer is not clear to me. I can't parse `different document links to email & letter` unambiguously.

Comment: I don't think any individual row in document would be shared between emails & letters. Any row should either belong to Letter or Email. I think my question is quite clear as with the example above, the only thing similar is the table structure of document, but unfortunately it seems I cannot easily reuse this document table as the FK of DocUUID can only be tight to one other table column. Is this clear enough ?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one of those fk constraints works per column of the same instance of the table. You would have to add one column for each fk. Or have two `documentstore` tables.

As you clarified, the same row in `documentstore` belongs to either a letter or an email, but only to a *single* one of those, while each letter / email can have multiple documents.
Hence my new advice: stick with table design you have now, but create **two separate tables**. There is no gain in having them in the same table. The fact that both tables share the same structure is *no good reason* to share the data.

You *can* have `schema_a.documentstore` and `schema_b.documentstore` inheriting from `master.documentstore`. That would mainly be useful if you have use cases dealing with all rows in both tables at once. Be sure to read the chapter about [limitations of inheritance in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS). In particular, it won't allow you to define a single fk constraint:

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
>   both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

Related answers with code examples:
[Find out which schema based on table values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902072/find-out-which-schema-based-on-table-values/12902441#12902441)
[Create a table of two types in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565183/create-a-table-of-two-types-in-postgresql/21565888#21565888)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is a one to many mapping from Email to DocumentStore table via the DocUUID. If I were to include DocUUID as foreign key in letter and email, it would introduce redundant information in Email & Letter...

Comment: Could you show me how does inheritance help here in terms of the one to many mapping ?

Comment: I have 1:m relationship between letter and Doc and another 1:n relationship between email and Doc. Does that make n:m relationship between all those ?

Comment: could you please give some example code for my case if you think your answer could solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Gob00st: I suspect that a Doc can also be used in multiple letters / emails. That would make it an n:m relationship. "One letter can have multiple docs, one doc can be used in multiple letters." Are you sure you don't need that?

Comment: A Doc can only be used in one email or letter. I am sure I don't need a doc can be used in more than one email or letter.

Answer (score 0):

same table is fine.  then you have some choice - you may add a 'type' column if you need to differntiate inside the same table - which i think you don't really need or you build associative classes to the other things like this:

```
Doc_email
----------
DocUUID
EmailUUID
```

and

```
Doc_letter
-----------
DocUUID
LetterUUID
```

Comment: So you are against having a extra enum type in the DocumentStore table ? And what do you mean associative classes ? Can you elaborate your example a bit more ? Thanks

Comment: associative tables link two other atomic tables together without impacting either one.  For the enum, I dont find that is typically required.  Although you have not specified your business rules, which may be some kind of special case.